# Laravel Vue scaffolding, Auth and Nova installation order?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

If project requires: Laravel 6, Vue scaffolding, Auth and Laravel Nova.
Is there any specific order of installation of all those tools to get it all installed right?

Does Nova requires that Laravel authentication to be installed prior to Nova?
Does Nova comes with it's own user authentication?
Will Nova conflict with Laravel Auth that was installed prior to Nova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did several tests and found no difference in the results with different order of Laravel, Auth, Nova and Vue installation.
Looks like Nova doesn't create additional Users table, and uses the one that comes with Laravel.

Logical installation order might be:

```
laravel new MyProjectName
php artisan ui vue --auth (use --auth flag if you need authentication)
php artisan nova:install (make sure you have copied Nova files first)
```